# Линейный поиск по книге Т. Кормена. Что он имеет ввиду?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Вот его псевдокод линейного поиска числа в массиве:

> ```
> 1. Установить значение answer равным NOT-FOUND.
> 2. Для каждого индекса i, пробегающего поочередно значение от 1 до п
> А. Если A[i] = х, установить значение answer равным i.
> 3. В качестве выходного вернуть значение answer
> ```

далее он поясняет:

> ```
> Будем счи­тать, что каждое выполнение шага i требует времени t от i, 
> где t от i - некоторые константы, не зависящие от n
> ```

и приводит формулы времени выполнения процедуры:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите расшифровать. Время выполнения проверки на равенство i и n умножается на результат n+1 ? Почему умножается? Ну дальше этого я и не продвинулся.

Comment: Если одна команда требует времени t, то сколько времени поторебуется, чтобы выполни n таких комманд? t * n. Либо вопрос посложнее чем мне кажется, либо это и есть ответ

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko тогда почему не домножаются t1 ? Почему в первой формуле 0 и почему не домножается t3?

Comment: Все зависит от того, откуда эти t1, t3 взялись и ч то они значат. Если они плюсуются, значит это константы, которые не зависят от количества элементов. Скажем, чтобы вызовать какой-то методв всегда надо t1 времени вне завиимости от того 0 элементов или 100, потому это время плюсуется

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну ведь все очевидно!

```
1. Установить значение answer равным NOT-FOUND.
```

Это - t<sub>1</sub>, выполняется один раз

```
2. Для каждого индекса i, пробегающего поочередно значение от 1 до п
```

Это - член t<sub>2</sub>', умноженный на (n+1) - служебное время цикла (проверка значения i и его увеличение). Один лишний раз - при завершении цикла.

```
А. Если A[i] = х, установить значение answer равным i.
```

Следующий член - n раз проверка значения `A[i]` (t<sub>2A</sub>'), а за ним - первая формула для случая, когда ни одного раза проверка не выполнена (значение `answer` не присваивается), вторая - худший вариант, когда это делается n раз (t<sub>2A</sub>")...

```
3. В качестве выходного вернуть значение answer
```

Значение t<sub>3</sub> - однократно.